# Making devices accessible to all users in a group

Tags: permissions, udev

I have two devices, /dev/comedi0 and a USB device, which I want to make accessible to all users in the group scan. I have tried creating a udev rule to do this, but without success:

```
KERNEL=="comedi*", MODE="0660", GROUP="scan"
```

When I check the permissions (after reboot):

```
$ls -la /dev/comedi0
crw-rw---- 1 root root 98, 0 Dec 17 16:44 /dev/comedi0
```

And when I try and use the device, I get the same error (can't open card /dev/comedi0) that I got before I figured out that it's a permissions problem. If I change the permissions manually (`chmod 666 /dev/comedi0`), I can use the card. I know this isn't the same as the permissions I'm setting in udev, but I want it to be accessible to any user in group scan, not just any user.

I believe the rule for the USB device will need to look something like this:

```
SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTR{idVendor}=="${vendor ID}", ATTR{idProduct}=="${product ID}", MODE="0660", GROUP="scan"
```

where I will substitute the vendor and product IDs.

A point of note is that the group scan is not a local group - authentication is handled by a server, so the group scan does not exist locally (i.e.: not in /etc/group).

## edit

relevant lines from `udevadm test $(udevadm info -q path -n /dev/ttyUSB0)`:

```
GROUP 24001 /etc/udev/rules.d/91-apt-stage.rules:1
MODE 0660 /etc/udev/rules.d/91-apt-stage.rules:1
handling device node '/dev/ttyUSB0', devnum=c188:0, mode=0660, uid=0, gid=24001
set permissions /dev/ttyUSB0, 020660, uid=0, gid=24001
setting mode of /dev/ttyUSB0 to 020660 failed: Operation not permitted
setting owner of /dev/ttyUSB0 to uid=0, gid=24001 failed: Operation not permitted
```

So it's failing to set the group. I also tried changing the rule so the group and owner were set using the GID and my UID, but that gave the same error.

Comment: But the permissions you set manually is diff from the permissions set using udev!

Comment: Yes, they are different, because /dev/comedi0 belongs to group root, so setting r/w permissions for all means I can use it (in group scan). I want it to have r/w permissions for any user in group scan. I'll edit the original post to reflect my awareness of this.

Comment: @WillHardiman Would you add the full setup to the question? like where did you put the rule. It does not seem running at all. By the way the group should be local. udev is a very low level system.

Comment: I didn't find a good solution in the end - I just added a few users to the group for the card and gave up. I think it might work if I created a local group, and set permissions using that.